# using awk on only files which START with 'xyz'

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, awk

I have 3 files in a directory: `xyz1.txt`, `xyz2.txt`, `rst_xyz.txt` and I want to work with ONLY the first two (those which start with xyz). The command `ls | awk '/xyz/{print $1}'` will return all three of them. What alterations can I make to the command to specify ONLY the xyz* files? I tried `ls | awk '/^xyz/{print $1}'` thinking that it would make sure the file started with xyz, but that did not exclude `rst_xyz.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

You want

```
awk '...' xyz*
```

If, for some very odd reason, you want to do this entirely within awk:

```
awk 'FILENAME ~ /^xyz/ { .... }' *
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice not to parse `ls` - that had never occurred to me! The very odd reason is simply so that I can learn exactly how awk works and how to implement regex's in it. I am trying to simply print all files beginning with 'xyz' as you can see from my original question. In your example, `awk 'FILENAME ~ /^xyz/ { print $1}'` would be the corollary, but it does not print anything to the screen.

Comment: @Laurbert515 You can `{print FILENAME}`.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was, in fact, parsing ls. I am actually using "ls --color" and when I use "ls --color=none | ..." I get the correct thing with my original command.

Comment: use `--color=auto`. This only colors the output when it's going to a terminal, not when it's redirected to a pipe or file.

Comment: @Laurbert515, another reason not to parse `ls`

Answer (score 1):

no need for awk. just use filename glob:

```
ls xyz*
```

most likely you will want to pipe the filenames to work on them? like this maybe?

```
ls xyz* | some other commands
```

in that case it is better to use a for loop.

```
for filename in xyz*
do
  some other commands "$filename"
done
```

note that in the first variant the filenames will come as a stream to stdin of `some other commands` while in the for loop the filenames will come one by one as a command line argument for `some other command`.

Comment: Thank you. There are a variety of ways to do the task in question, but I was specifically asking for the awk method because I am trying to learn awk.

Comment: ok i understand. in that case you should provide more details about your system in your question because `awk '/^xyz/{print $1}'` works as expected on my system. also your question is probably better asked on stackoverflow.com as it is a programming question.

Comment: Thank you, I will repost on stackoverflow. To be clear though, `/^xyz/` performs the desired function on your system? If that is the case, then I will update my question on stackoverflow with more details about my system if I cannot figure out the problem on my own.

Comment: There's no reason to repost this on SO. It's in the overlap between SU, SO, and unix.SE, and one question should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | awk '/^xyz/'
```

Your original solution was just missing the `^` in the regep, which anchors the match to the beginning of the line. You don't need a `print` block because the default action when finding a match is to print the line. If you want to be explicit, you could write:

```
ls | awk '/^xyz/ {print $0}'
```

You should use `$0` rather than `$1` in case the filename contains spaces (although if the filename contains newline, this will still treat it as multiple names).

Comment: I actually have the `/^xyz/` solution in my original question and it does not work on my system. Is my issue just system dependent you think?

Comment: I don't think it should be system-dependent. This is an extremely basic command and should work in every version of `awk`. I just tried it on both OS X and Debian Linux and it worked fine. I suspect you mistyped something when you tried it.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment on the selected answer. I was typing it correctly, but I was piping from "ls --color" and not just "ls".